# Git clone/push/pull of a remote share fails

Tags: windows, git

a few of us use a bare repository on a network share ( u:\data\some_repo.git) and this works fine with the expected limitations

However, just recently I have been unable to perform any typical git activities associated with the bare respository: push pull clone.

All activities fail with:

> fatal: 'u:\data\some_repo.git' does not appear to be a
> git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I do have access and I can browse this location fine. If I copy some_repo.git to my local machine and do a git clone /c/Temp/some_repo.git it works.

There is no latency issue, I have full access, I have tried prepending file:/// with no luck. a GIT_TRACE does not show anything

> GIT_TRACE=1 git clone "/u/data/some_repo.git" 12:52:37.433340
> exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir:
> C:/STORAGE/Application/Git/mingw64/bin 12:52:37.435332 git.c:444
> trace: built-in: git clone u:/data/some_repo.git Cloning into
> 'InternalTestInterface'... 12:52:38.129124 run-command.c:663
> trace: run_command: unset GIT_DIR; 'git-upload-pack
> '''u:/data/some_repo.git'''' 12:52:38.370091 exec-cmd.c:237
> trace: resolved executable dir:
> C:/STORAGE/Application/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core 12:52:38.370091
> git.c:444               trace: built-in: git upload-pack
> u:/data/some_repo.git fatal: 'Hu:/data/some_repo.git' does not appear
> to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Any idea how to resolve this

--update--

as requested, attempting to perform a git init:

```
/u/data/test.git 
$ git init error: fstat on
//FQDN.com/site_###/Groups/data/test.git/.git/config failed: Invalid
argument fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same setup at work, with the same network drive (also named `U:\`!)

And I had the same issue at some point, apparently due to some background synchronisation/backup process which was keeping an handle on some of the files of the Git bare repository.

Try first to see if you can re-create a separate bare repo, for testing, and push to it:

```
git init U:\data\test.git
cd path\to\local\repo
git remote add origin2 U:\data\test.git
git push origin2 master
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I think you might be right but its trying to figure out what. Something must be holding the file for a fstat to fail

Comment: @Naib In my case, it was related to romaing profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-roaming-user-profiles) whose backup was problematic.